# Using a Jelly Bag

Tags: fruit, jelly

I am attempting to make Sea Buckthorn jelly (as in jam jelly rather than gelatin jelly), but am having an issue with straining the juice.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. freeze the berries on the branches (this makes them much easier to pick)
2. defrost the berries, this resulted in some liquid already in with the berries, so I didn't add any more before boiling
3. boiled the berries for a few minutes, about 10, to break them up a little
4. pushed the berries though a coarse sieve to crush them and remove seeds & pulp.

I'm now on the stage where I'm supposed to strain the resultant juice through a jelly bag - I have left the mixture in the bag overnight and it doesn't seem to have moved.

I suppose the bag is clogged with fruit pulp, and the rest of the juice most likely will not go through.

Is there anything I can do a make the remaining juice go through? I have been told never to squeeze the jelly bag as this will make the jelly cloudy.

I am happy to accept cloudy jelly on this first attempt if there is nothing that can be done; but in that case, what can be done in the future?

Comment: I don't know about your berries, but I have squeezed juice out of raspberries using a cheesecloth, and the jelly didn't become cloudy. No idea if there is something special about other berries though.

Comment: I noticed this with Pomegranite.  Ran the seeds through my mega-juicer, and the resulting liquid was cloudy. It took FOREVER to go through the jelly bag, and had to run it through a coffee filter as well to get clear jelly.  It is probably too many micro-particulates clogging up the holes in the bag.  Probably better to just give them a good mash and let them sit.